# Frame not in module while executing code in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting Frame not in module while executing the following code in Xamarin.Forms

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://abcd.com");

        string json = @"{""userNo"":""xyz"",""passcode"":""12345""}";

        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage rsponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("/credentialCheckAp.cgi", content); // Problem Occurs in this line while debugging 
        var result = await rsponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: What have you tried? Here is some tips: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27308/debugger-doesnt-work-frame-not-in-module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179513/xamarin-android-exception-causes-frame-not-in-module

Comment: @YuriS I have tried all the possible solutions on that Xamarin forum thread with no luck

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately :-) ) I cannot reproduce this, so I cannot help you